# IShellExecuteHook.Execute

Tags: windows, delphi, api, shell

Can someone show me how to use "IShellExecuteHook.Execute" in Delphi please?

info: [IShellExecuteHook::Execute Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775099%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Description:
This method is called any time the ShellExecute or ShellExecuteEx functions are
called. This happens when a file is double-clicked in Explorer or when the Run dialog
box is used.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The following EDN link looks like it will give you what you need: [How to hook ShellExecute calls (IShellExecuteHook)](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/13444)

Be aware that it won't work in 64 bit Windows because that requires 64 bit shell extensions and because Delphi only produces 32 bit images you would need to use a different language.  I also note that IShellExecuteHook is deprecated as of Vista.

Comment: Thanks David. There is also some good explanation in this book: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Tomes-Delphi-Wordware-Developers-Library/dp/1556227493 which I found.