# Need some explanations on this Delphi code

Tags: windows, delphi, api, hook, shellexecute

I have [this code](http://i51.tinypic.com/20sx8vm.png) and need some explanation on these questions:

- What is that trailing "_TLB" after "ShellExecHookXample" in first uses section?
- How should I use this code in Delphi 7 and make stand-alone exe file? (I don't know what's the proper place to put codes and call its method. Since it seems to be a unit or what?)
- if possible please describe the code for me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: update the code to the question! what you don't understand? be more specific.

Comment: No sense in trying to explain that code if you don't even know where to put code. I suggest you get a book covering the basics of Delphi and start out with a few simple applications. Then you can try to understand the code in question. If you have **specific** questions, you can ask on SO.

Comment: The problem is that you don't know Delphi and are trying to do some pretty advanced stuff with it. You should be writing Hello world programs, since it appears you don't know what a Unit is. Also, an image doesn't qualify as "code"!

Comment: You need to add the code to the question.

Comment: @Nick Hodges here is the link:http://i51.tinypic.com/20sx8vm.png or http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/delphikylix/421265/421265/ishellexecutehookexecute/

Answer (score 5):

The _TLB is stands for type library. It looks like you are trying to implement [`IShellExecuteHook.Execute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775099%28VS.85%29.aspx) and have so far found some code [here](http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/delphikylix/421265/421265/ishellexecutehookexecute/). However, I'm guessing because you didn't tell us. You are likely to get better answers if you are able to to spend more effort describing what it is you are trying to achieve.

If my guess is correct you should take a look at this question: [IShellExecuteHook.Execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806147/ishellexecutehook-execute) which I believe will explain how to solve your actual problem.

Comment: The truth is that I'm not Delphi programmer and had some experience with it making some simple windows Apps before. so after some time I am in the need to make some app for monitoring executable files and do some logs.

Comment: @silvercover ShellExecute is but one way for executables to start. They get started up in many other ways too. Can't you use a 3rd party tool for this?

Comment: I've found this code and honestly don't know how to deal with COM and Unit manipulations and just need its output. can you tell me the step-by-step way with mentioned code to make my final exe in Delphi?

Comment: @silvercover No I can't. How could I do that? I've absolutely no idea what you want. I don't mean to be harsh, I'm just speaking the truth. Did you follow the link in my answer yet?

Comment: Well I know some basics about IShellExecuteHook.Execute but I have hard time using available tips and techniques in Delphi. because that's not simple 1 unit coding which I've learned from starter books. and about the second link, that's my own topic in programmersheaven and my problem still resists.

Comment: @silvercover I mean the other link in the second paragraph.

Comment: @silvercover It will come back to life in due course. The Code Central server appears to be down. What is most irritating is that you asked "can you tell me the step-by-step way with mentioned code to make my final exe in Delphi" before even attempting to read the links I served up for you. That is quite simply rude. At least make the effort to understand it yourself first before you ask somebody else to do your work for you!

Comment: I am busy with this problem for almost about two weeks and you can not judge me that I'm lazy or rude! just do some search and find my topics in many forums. I've also tried to read some book, but I still have problem. and for that step-by-step request you should notice that I just need the way not code!

Comment: @silvercode You didn't attempt to read the link I sent you and instead asked me to spend my valuable time. That's rude. I wish you good luck with your continued efforts in implementing this.

Comment: @silvercode And now I see that the SO question I referred you was one asked by yourself, to which you make no reference. Please stop wasting our time and treat people with more respect.

Comment: for those you though I'm lazy or something, please look at this honest and helpful explanation I've got here: [Yahoo Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/?qid=20110202063620AAP6ts7). In the future please do not try to judge someone based on what it looks like and not the truth.

Comment: @silvercover That's very nice, but it's just a shame that the answer you got there is inaccurate. The answer you got there is the same erroneous one that Yuriy Vikulov gave you here. And you may have noticed the up-votes next to my latest comment indicating that I was far from alone in my opinion.

Comment: But you know the point is to explain and not blame. no matter the  hole answer is wrong or partially right.

Comment: @Solvercover I was frustrated because I have told you the answer twice now but you won't listen and you keep asking the same question. That EDN download gives you a complete implementation of IShellExecuteHook. Why won't you listen?

Answer (score 2):

ShellExecHookXample_tlb means that this unit was imported from com (activex) object with an internal delphi tool (Project->Import type library...) 
it reads public methods,events, properties of com (activex) object and generates pas unit with appropriate classes/interfaces. Usually you can find it in delphi folders.

Comment: I think it's the other way round here. This is an interface that you implements rather than one that Windows implements.

Comment: but this interface uses imported type library, imho

Comment: @Yuriy Not as I understand it. This interface is not implemented by Windows. Instead you implement it and register it with Windows. Windows then creates and calls your COM object when ShellExecute happens.

Comment: @David may be myenglish is not good. I do not dispute with you. i agree with you about this interface (in the shown code). I mean that ShellExecHookXample_tlb was likely generated from  com (activex) object with an internal delphi tool

Comment: @Yuriy The TLB I will likely have been built from scratch with the Delphi ActiveX type library designer.

Comment: You are right, it could be. There is a little information to be sure for 100%

Comment: @Yuriy Now, that statement, I do agree with!